# AWS cognito user migration pool trigger not working on login flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS cognito pool migration using Lambda function with cognito execution role
Following is my new pool app client setting

[image]

or

[image]
AWS doc says

> User migration authentication flow A user migration Lambda trigger
>   allows easy migration of users from a legacy user management system
>   into your user pool. To avoid making your users reset their passwords
>   during user migration, choose the USER_PASSWORD_AUTH authentication
>   flow. This flow sends your users' passwords to the service over an
>   encrypted SSL connection during authentication.
>
> When you have completed migrating all your users, we recommend
>   switching flows to the more secure SRP flow. The SRP flow does not
>   send any passwords over the network.

I have created lambda function with role "AmazonCognitoPowerUser"

```
        async function authenticateUser(cognitoISP: CognitoIdentityServiceProvider, username: string, password: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
            console.log(`authenticateUser: user='${username}'`);

            const params: AdminInitiateAuthRequest = {
                AuthFlow: 'ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
                AuthParameters: {
                    PASSWORD: password,
                    USERNAME: username,
                },
                ClientId: OLD_CLIENT_ID,
                UserPoolId: OLD_USER_POOL_ID,
            };
            const cognitoResponse = await cognitoISP.adminInitiateAuth(params).promise();
            const awsError: AWSError = cognitoResponse as any as AWSError;
            if (awsError.code && awsError.message) {
                console.log(`authenticateUser: error ${JSON.stringify(awsError)}`);
                return undefined;
            }
            console.log(`authenticateUser: found ${JSON.stringify(cognitoResponse)}`);

            return lookupUser(cognitoISP, username);
        }

        async function lookupUser(cognitoISP: CognitoIdentityServiceProvider, username: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
            console.log(`lookupUser: user='${username}'`);
            const params = {
                UserPoolId: OLD_USER_POOL_ID,
                Username: username,
            };
            const cognitoResponse = await cognitoISP.adminGetUser(params).promise();
            const awsError: AWSError = cognitoResponse as any as AWSError;
            if (awsError.code && awsError.message) {
                console.log(`lookupUser: error ${JSON.stringify(awsError)}`);
                return undefined;
            }
            console.log(`lookupUser: found ${JSON.stringify(cognitoResponse)}`);

            const userAttributes = cognitoResponse.UserAttributes ? cognitoResponse.UserAttributes.reduce((acc, entry) => ({
                ...acc,
                [entry.Name]: entry.Value,
            }), {} as {[key: string]: string | undefined}) : {};
            const user: User = {
                userAttributes,
                userName: cognitoResponse.Username,
            };
            console.log(`lookupUser: response ${JSON.stringify(user)}`);
            return user;
        }

        async function onUserMigrationAuthentication(cognitoISP: CognitoIdentityServiceProvider, event: CognitoUserPoolTriggerEvent) {
            // authenticate the user with your existing user directory service
            const user = await authenticateUser(cognitoISP, event.userName!, event.request.password!);
            if (!user) {
                throw new Error('Bad credentials');
            }

            event.response.userAttributes = {
                // old_username: user.userName,
                // 'custom:tenant': user.userAttributes['custom:tenant'],
                email: user.userAttributes.email!,
                email_verified: 'true',
                preferred_username: user.userAttributes.preferred_username!,
            };
            event.response.finalUserStatus = 'CONFIRMED';
            event.response.messageAction = 'SUPPRESS';

            console.log(`Authentication - response: ${JSON.stringify(event.response)}`);
            return event;
        }

        async function onUserMigrationForgotPassword(cognitoISP: CognitoIdentityServiceProvider, event: CognitoUserPoolTriggerEvent) {
            // Lookup the user in your existing user directory service
            const user = await lookupUser(cognitoISP, event.userName!);
            if (!user) {
                throw new Error('Bad credentials');
            }

            event.response.userAttributes = {
                // old_username: user.userName,
                // 'custom:tenant': user.userAttributes['custom:tenant'],
                email: user.userAttributes.email!,
                email_verified: 'true',
                preferred_username: user.userAttributes.preferred_username!,
            };
            event.response.messageAction = 'SUPPRESS';

            console.log(`Forgot password - response: ${JSON.stringify(event.response)}`);

            return event;
        }

        export const handler = async (event: CognitoUserPoolTriggerEvent, context: Context): Promise<CognitoUserPoolTriggerEvent> => {
            const options: CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.Types.ClientConfiguration = {
                region: OLD_USER_POOL_REGION,
            };
            if (OLD_ROLE_ARN) {
                options.credentials = new ChainableTemporaryCredentials({
                    params: {
                        ExternalId: OLD_EXTERNAL_ID,
                        RoleArn: OLD_ROLE_ARN,
                        RoleSessionName: context.awsRequestId,
                    },
                });
            }
            const cognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider(options);

            switch (event.triggerSource) {
                case 'UserMigration_Authentication':
                    return onUserMigrationAuthentication(cognitoIdentityServiceProvider, event);
                case 'UserMigration_ForgotPassword':
                    return onUserMigrationForgotPassword(cognitoIdentityServiceProvider, event);
                default:
                    throw new Error(`Bad triggerSource ${event.triggerSource}`);
            }
        }
```

and added trigger into new pool,

[image]

**After many attempt Lambda trigger is not working on login always getting error  .**

```
  {__type: "NotAuthorizedException", message: "Incorrect username or password."}
       message: "Incorrect username or password."
     __type: "NotAuthorizedException"
```

**Though its working fine if we use forget passwords flow after reset password user migrated to new pool**

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-import-using-lambda.html

**UPDATED :**

When directly run test on lambda using following json

```
  {
   "version": "1",
   "triggerSource": "UserMigration_Authentication",
   "region": "ap-south-1",
   "userPoolId": "ap-XXXXXXXXX2",
   "userName": "vaquar.test@gmail.com",
   "callerContext": {
   "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-unknown-unknown",
   "clientId": "1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXfgk"
   },
   "request": {
   "password": "vkhan",
   "validationData": null,
   "userAttributes": null
    },
   "response": {
    "userAttributes": null,
    "forceAliasCreation": null,
    "finalUserStatus": null,
    "messageAction": null,
    "desiredDeliveryMediums": null
    }
  }
```

Then getting following response and user migrated into new pool means we have issue in trigger during login.

```
 INFO   Authentication - response: {"userAttributes":{"email":"vaquar.test@gmail.com","email_verified":"true"},"forceAliasCreation":null,"finalUserStatus":"CONFIRMED","messageAction":"SUPPRESS","desiredDeliveryMediums":null}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Lambda trigger, Cognito service invokes Lambda function. So Cognito will require [permission to invoke Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html#permissions-resource-serviceinvoke). How are you configuring the Lambda trigger on your userpool? If you are using AWS Cognito console, the permission should be set automatically.

You may also [verify if the user already exists in the new userpool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/how-to-manage-user-accounts.html#cognito-user-pools-manage-user-accounts-searching-for-users-using-console) that could cause such behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that your application is using OAUTH flow USER_PASSWORD instead of the default  USER_SRP_AUTH.

For reference: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-import-using-lambda.html)