# AWS Lambda UserMigration_ForgotPassword Trigger | Not Migrating Users

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-serverless

So I'm trying to migrate users stored in dynamodb to a cognito user pool, but the `UserMigration_ForgotPassword` trigger simply isn't working. I searched everywhere and found no solution to my problem. I also followed the documentation to the letter, still nothing. Here is what my code looks like in lambda:

```
else if (event.triggerSource === 'UserMigration_ForgotPassword') {
  console.log('forgot password trigger working')
  user = await findUser(event.userName) 
    if (user) {
     console.log('user found!')
     const { Item } = user 
     console.log(Item)

     event.response.userAttributes = {
       'email': Item.email,
       'email_verified': Item.emailVerified
     }
     event.response.messageAction = 'SUPPRESS'
     console.log(event)
     context.succeed(event);
   } else {
     console.log('User does not exists')
     callback(Error('Bad Password'))
 }
```

Here is what I get on cloudwatch:

```
2020-09-04T12:13:12.895Z    786f09ce-91b7-4051-ade6-************    INFO    forgot password trigger working
2020-09-04T12:13:12.975Z    786f09ce-91b7-4051-ade6-************    INFO    user found!
2020-09-04T12:13:12.977Z    786f09ce-91b7-4051-ade6-************    INFO    {
  emailVerified: true,
  password: '************************',
  salt: '',
  phone_number: '+1111111111',
  internal_user_id: '*****',
  username: 'name@email.com',
  email: 'name@email.com',
  name: 'name'
}
2020-09-04T12:13:12.977Z    786f09ce-91b7-4051-ade6-************    INFO    {
  version: '1',
  triggerSource: 'UserMigration_ForgotPassword',
  region: 'us-****-*',
  userPoolId: 'us-****-*_********',
  userName: 'name@email.com',
  callerContext: {
    awsSdkVersion: 'aws-sdk-unknown-unknown',
    clientId: '**************'
  },
  request: { password: null, validationData: null, userAttributes: null },
  response: {
    userAttributes: {
      email: 'name@email.com',
      email_verified: true
    },
    forceAliasCreation: null,
    messageAction: 'SUPPRESS',
    desiredDeliveryMediums: null
  }
}
```

I can safely conclude that the trigger is working, it is able to get the user from dynamodb and it is able to build the proper response object. But, still for some reason, it cannot import the user. This is the error that I get:

```
{code: "UserNotFoundException", name: "UserNotFoundException", message: "Exception migrating user in app client *************************"}
```

Also, the lambda trigger has access to dynamodb, it can invoke the function, it can log in cloudwatch and of course, it is hooked up to the trigger in cognito. I am using the serverless framework in case you are wondering.

Finally, I want to point out that `UserMigration_Authentication` is working properly, which makes it even weirder (at least for me).

Would be great to know the source of the problem.

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT 1**

I'm not sure if this is related to the current problem, but most likely is. One more thing that I did to prevent `UserNotFoundException`, I "ENABLED" `PreventUserExistenceErrors`. Here is a link to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pool-managing-errors.html). Still the error appears.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62355507/aws-cognito-user-migration-pool-trigger-not-working-on-login-flow

Comment: Hi vaquarkhan, thanks for the pointer. I added the "lambda:InvokeFunction" but there is nothing that is happening. I'm still not able to migrate users when they forget their password

Comment: We have catch with user migration lambda its working only when you click forget password, i am exploring seemsless migration will update my answer once get fix , sad part Amazon team not give good support to stackoverflow and didn't answer any questions .

Comment: May I ask, how did you make it work when user clicks on forget password? Do you have any documentation besides amazon's (which I tried and many other flavors of it)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have shared my lambda function if u add cognito pool id and deploy with proper role it will give you error on login so you need to handle in ur app three failed attampt show forgot password and once user enter Otp msg and reset password user will move to new pool.

Comment: The forget password is working in that scenario, I guess because you are moving from one user pool to another but in my case, I'm moving from dynamodb to a user pool. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as to why the trigger wasn't working is because nothing was passed in the `ClientMetadata` key. For some reason, I didn't find the documentation clear enough. So in my case:

```
$result = $client->forgotPassword([
    'AnalyticsMetadata' => [
        'AnalyticsEndpointId' => '<string>',
    ],
    'ClientId' => '<string>', 
    'ClientMetadata' => ['<string>', ...], // <- This needs to be filled
    'SecretHash' => '<string>',
    'UserContextData' => [
        'EncodedData' => '<string>',
    ],
    'Username' => '<string>', 
]);
```

When the `ClientMetadata` key is filled, it will trigger the pre sign-up, custom message, and user migration lambda functions.

I leave this here in case anyone needs help!

Comment: What data do we pass to ClientMetadata in the forget password use case.