# AWS Cognito UserMigration_ForgotPassword not trigger on forgot_password flow

Tags: boto3, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I am doing an authentication project with Cognito and I am trying to migrate my user to cognito pool with UserMigration in custom trigger flow using `forgot password flow` (following documentation, there are 2 ways to trigger this are sign-in and forgot-password [1]) on sign-in the trigger works properly but the problem occurs on **forgot password, the trigger is not working, not any trigger in cloudwatch-log!**
I have been trying and searching many where but, still not working. Here is my lambda code with python boto3. that used on forgot-password:

```
def forgot_password(username):
    try:
        response = cognito_client.forgot_password(
            ClientId=MY_APP_CLIENT_ID,
            SecretHash=MY_SECRET_HASH,
            Username=username,
            ClientMetadata={"key":"value"}
        )
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
```

my expectation is the User Migration trigger should work and wake in forgot-password flow simply.

Thank you in advance for helping or answering this issue

Thanks a lot :)

Note: I also add `ClientMetadata` like in this question[2] but, the trigger is still not working as expected.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-migrate-user.html#aws-lambda-triggers-user-migration-example-1

[2] [AWS Lambda UserMigration_ForgotPassword Trigger | Not Migrating Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63741402/aws-lambda-usermigration-forgotpassword-trigger-not-migrating-users)

Comment: DId you find a solution to this ?

Comment: no, I have moved to a new project and also just pause on implementation in Cognito

Answer (score 0):

Not confident with python boto3, but I would suggest also to double check you're using `USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` flow → [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-import-using-lambda.html)

Comment: Thats for Signin flow not forgot password.